# Macros that directly reference spreadsheet/csv

Tags: macros, csv

I would really like is to get a row from a CSV, format it, and then put it in my text.

Say for example I have a spreadsheet that has data about cities, for example "Montreal, 1000, Victoria, Bananas" is line 5.

I would like to be able to call on line 5 and automatically format it into:

***Montreal***. *Population*: 1000. The mayor's name is Victoria and the primary export is bananas.

Is this possible? How might one do it?

Bonus: It would be even more useful if I could do it in such a way that I instead call on Montreal directly instead of line 5, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Take a look at the packages `datatool`, `csvsimple`, or `pgfplotstable`, one of those might be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.csv}
Vancouver, 2000, Ivan, Avocados
Edmonton, 3000, Scarlet, Mangos
Saskatoon, 4000, Hilbert, Strawberries
Halifax, 12, Dilbert, Kiwis
Montreal, 1000, Victoria, Bananas
Toronto, 5000, Edward, Blueberries
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

% Load CSV file
\DTLloaddb[
  noheader,
  keys={city,population,mayor,export}
]{names}{mydata.csv}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printcity}{ m }{%
  \textbf{#1}. % Print city
  \textit{Population}: \DTLfetch{names}{city}{#1}{population}. % Print population
  \textit{Export}: \DTLfetch{names}{city}{#1}{export}.
}

\begin{document}

\printcity{Toronto}

\printcity{Edmonton}

\printcity{Montreal}

\end{document}
```

You can add conditionals for existence of content, if need be. However, since you're creating the database, there's probably no need for that.

Comment: This works great - thanks a ton! But I've been using the conditionals as not every field applies to every item, and my \ifx statement from \newcommand doesn't seem to map over nicely... not sure how to write this up!

Comment: @Paul: Sure. You can use conditionals to filter what you want to print... but yes, you need to provide more detail.

Comment: I have some empty cells that normally need to be formatted. 

For example, “Montreal. Population: 3000. Export: Bananas. Mayor: Steve.”, but then “Toronto. Population: 5. Mayor: Evelyn.” So I need not to have the title bit for “export” in Toronto. Is that enough?

Comment: @Paul: Right, so some fields are missing for some entries. Sure. Let me figure something out.

Comment: @Paul: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/8bspscd3). I've somewhat abstracted the components, using `\printentry` as the main driver, taking the city as the argument. Then `\printcity` prints the city, `\printpopulation` prints the population and `\printexport` prints the export. In the `\printexport` macro, I store the output of `\DTLfetch` inside a box (`\testbox`), for which I can then test the width (`\ifdim\wd\testbox=0pt <true>\else <false>\fi`). Here one can condition on what to do if it's empty or not.

Comment: Ah, there’s no easy way to use \ifx? I’ll try that as soon as I get home! Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: The retrieval of content from a data table in this case is not expandable for testing, so an "easy" way to achieve this is to store the content in a box that one can measure. The box content has to be expanded to be stored, similar to printing.

Comment: Amazing! This is working well, though I am confused about one thing and google isn't helping - I can't seem to italicize the \usebox! I can underline it, but italicizing and bolding don't work, both of which would be very handy.

I could just add \textit{...} on my data in my csv, but that would be cumbersome for a few reasons. Any way around that?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Paul: Instead of `\usebox\testbox`, fetch the item again: `\textit{\DTLfetch{names}{city}{#1}{export}}`.